# meteor loads script before DOM is ready - script is inside meteor.startup function

Tags: meteor, jquery-selectors, startup, iron-router

I'm trying to use document.querySelector("body") but i'm not getting any html elements back.

Why is that, the call to my script is inside meteor.startup?

I'm using iron router for my routing...

```
if(Meteor.isClient){

        Meteor.startup(function(){

            myScript()

        })

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor.startup can fire only after DOMContentLoaded event. But IronRouter will probably render the content after that later.

Try either using IronRouter's [onAfterAction](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#available-hook-methods) hook or template's [rendered callback](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
    Template.masterLayout.rendered = function(){

        myscript = myScriptJS()

    }
```

This calls myScriptJS() in the .rendered method of my [iron router layout](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#layouts). myScriptJS is executed and assigned to a global variable (myscript) because myScriptJS is a module pattern that is returning an object to it's namespace.

Now i can use this code everywhere:

```
myscript.counter()
```